# IIS 6.0 .htaccess

Tags: php, html, iis, iis-6

You can 'fake it' .php being a .html file using .htaccess:

AddType application/x-httpd.php .html .htm

how can i do this in using IIS 6.0?

Comment: @Gully - what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to the IIS Manager:

*Website Properties > Home Directory (Tab) > Configuration (Button) > Mappings (Tab)*

You *should* be able to assign what application/dll handles certain file extensions.